# Trying to compile Java Code I made on and was working on Eclipse in Linux Terminal Not Working

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to compile my code that I made in Eclipse in the Linux terminal and I am getting this error:

> Tree9.java:3: error: package java.util.Base64 does not exist
>
> import java.util.Base64.Decoder;

Does anyone know what is wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: add an import statement of the missing class.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to Java 8. The Javadoc for [`Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) says (in part)

> ```
> Since:
> 1.8
> ```

If you can't upgrade to Java 8, you could possibly change your code to use Apache [Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/index.html) which supports earlier versions of Java and includes a [`Base64`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) encoder/decoder.